# Issue while querying on a field that store a file path on ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having issue while trying to query or filter by a field that stores a file Path like `"c:\\change\\users\\89841b89-6529-43a6-9ca9-b2a851b4a7da\\example"`, I used to do a filter prefix without any issue in that field, but after updating ElasticSearch to version 1.4.0.
Any clue??? This is how my query looks like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "content.type:estimate"
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "prefix": {
      "storageDir": "c:\\change\\users\\89841b89-6529-43a6-9ca9-b2a851b4a7da\\example"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "modifiedWhen": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?  Are you receiving an error?  Not getting the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the field "storageDir" is marked as "not_analyzed" in the mapping. Otherwise it will split on slashes and dashes.

Comment: Thats exactly the issue, after updating the elasticSearch version the mapping lost the "not_analized" property, and the queries start failing.

Comment: You can change the mapping on a field but that will NOT apply to existing data.  I would recommend re-indexing all the data with the correct mapping.